# Java expression that takes an integer and returns the nearest 1000 multiple below it

Tags: java

This should be really trivial but all the methods I came up with are convoluted and waste operations (divide, take floor, scale up). Basically, I have random integers and I want to get the nearest 1000 multiple below it.

For example, **if I have 6432, I really want 6000, or if I have 888 I want 0**.

What the simplest expression that does this?

Comment: `x - (x % 1000)` for positive x

Comment: thats what im looking for. thanks

Comment: Or `(x / 1000) * 1000` if you're talking about integers.

Comment: @BrianRoach For negative x, both of these expressions round up instead of down, at least in Java.

Comment: It goes toward zero, yes, for both positive and negative x.

Comment: @BrianRoach Oh, I thought you were talking about "integers" as compared to "positive x". Since the actual question wants the nearest multiple *below* x, I thought my expression wouldn't be a full answer. I just assumed x was an integer as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing something like this:

```
int OrigionalNum = 1503;
int NewNum = (OrigionalNum / 1000) * 1000;
```

It will give you an answer of 1 for 1503 / 1000, and then multiply it by 1000.

Comment: Oops xD I didn't mean to use %!

Answer (score 3):

What you want is simply:

```
(number / 1000) * 1000;
```